# How do I select multiple lines in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have some HTML that follows this pattern:

```
<p>1. ALLCAPSTEXT1 - etc etc</p>
<p>01. lowercasetext1 - etc etc</p>
<p>02. lowercasetext1 - etc etc</p>
<p>2. ALLCAPSTEXT2 - etc etc</p>
<p>01. lowercasetext2 - etc etc</p>
<p>02. lowercasetext2 - etc etc</p>
<p>03. lowercasetext2 - etc etc</p>
<p>3. ALLCAPSTEXT3 - etcetc</p>
<p>01. lowercasetext3 - etc etc</p>
```

The number of lines after the "ALLCAPSWORD" line` vary, so it can be anywhere from 1 to 10+. I want to select all of these lines with this pattern (it goes up to 100+ lines).

So far I have:

```
<p>(\d+)\.\s[A-Z][A-Z]+(.+)</p>\n+<p>(.+)</p>\n+<p>\d+\.\s[A-Z][A-Z]+(.+)</p>
```

where the stuff in the first p tag captures the line with all-caps text, then go to the next line and the stuff in the p tag captures the line with lower-case text, and then go to the next line with all-caps text.

So I want it to get all of this:

```
<p>1. ALLCAPSTEXT1 - etc etc</p>
<p>01. lowercasetext1 - etc etc</p>
<p>02. lowercasetext1 - etc etc</p>
```

but it only captures the first line after the all-caps text and then skips to the next line with all-caps text and does the same thing.

```
<p>1. ALLCAPSTEXT1 - etc etc</p>
<p>01. lowercasetext1 - etc etc</p>
```

then goes to :

```
<p>2. ALLCAPSTEXT2 - etc etc</p>
<p>01. lowercasetext2 - etc etc</p
```

Any hints on how I could get it to capture all lines that have lowercase text till it reaches the next line with all-caps text, rinse and repeat?

Comment: Maybe [**`<p>\d+\.\s+[A-Z][A-Z]+(?:.+)</p>\R+(?:<p>\d+\.\s+[a-z].*\R*)+`**](https://regex101.com/r/RkuDXR/1)

Answer (score 0):

Could do it this way

`(?m)^.*?ALLCAPSTEXT.*(?:(?!^.*?ALLCAPSTEXT)[\S\s])*`

https://regex101.com/r/TfDsL9/1

Expanded

```
 (?m)
 ^ .*? ALLCAPSTEXT .* 
 (?:
      (?! ^ .*? ALLCAPSTEXT )
      [\S\s] 
 )*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>\d+\.\s[A-Z]+.*<\/p>(\n+<p>\d+\.\s[a-z]+.*<\/p>)+
```